# FACEBOOK "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Every now and then on my mobile app I get this error and this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

This error is coming from the following line;

```
if ((post.attachment.media !== undefined) && (post.attachment.media[0].type == "photo"))
```

I get it only sometimes, depending on the news feed I suppose. Sometimes it works perfectly and no error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that from time to time even though post.attachment.media is defined, it is not an array or it is an empty array.  You could safeguard for that with:

```
if ((post.attachment.media !== undefined) && 
    (post.attachment.media.length > 0) &&
    (post.attachment.media[0].type == "photo"))
```

Comment: thanks, I have included it and so far haven't got the error again! so it works! Thanks